# Android Toolbar back enable and set subtitle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I'm using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and `AppCompatActivity`. I've enabled back up button like this `supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`.

The fragment in side the activity will set the title and subtitle in `onResume()` like this

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
activity.setTitle(title);
activity.getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Bingo");
```

The problem is, when the fragment shows up `onResume` is called but subtitle is not shown. When I press power OFF and ON, means fragment goes to pause and resumes again. Now, subtitle is visible. I've tested on other android phone as well.

Can you please help me finding out the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the toolbar is not rendered when you are setting the subtitle.
Try this code,Set title and subtitle inside this method

```
private void setupToolbar(){
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
    if(toolbar != null){
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     }

     toolbar.post(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Subtitle);
        }
    });
}
```